# Check if there are higher values in 2 columns (C&D) on other sheet based on cell value in column B & autopopulate result

Tags: google-sheets, max, array-formulas, auto-populate

[Link to Google Sheet Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D0QduD7fq9vtJP_EiqP2jRJuRpN9usOW8_cEAnOdcqs/edit?usp=sharing)

In column E on sheet 'Calc', I want to check if there's a person in sheet 'Data' who has the same A value, but a higher value on B and C. Eventually I want to Return 'No' if not, return 'yes' if yes. If there's a person with the same A value who has a higher value on B but not on C (or vice versa) return 'maybe' with the name of the person(s). **Autopopulate** E with the returned value.

The values in columns B, C and D in 'Calc' are dynamic and will change based on other calculations. The B, C and D values in 'Data' are static. The length of both columns can differ.

**Some examples:**
Name 1 in sheet 'Calc' has the values of A89, B70, C70.
Person A in sheet 'Data' has the values of A89, B71, C75. No-one else has A89 and higher values on both B or C.
Return 'Yes'.

Name 1 in sheet 'Calc' has the values of A89, B70, C70.
Person A in sheet 'Data' has the values of A89, B60, C55. No-one else has A89 and higher values on both B or C.
Return 'No'.

Name 1 in sheet 'Calc' has the values of A89, B70, C70.
Person A in sheet 'Data' has the values of A89, B71, C55. No-one else has A89 and higher values on both B or C.
Return 'Maybe: Person A'.

Name 1 in sheet 'Calc' has the values of A89, B70, C70.
Person A in sheet 'Data' has the values of A89, B71, C55. Person B in sheet 'Data' has the values of A89, B55, C71. Person A has the highest value on B compared to the people in sheet 'Data' with A89 but a C lower than that of Name 1 in sheet 'Calc'. Person B has the highest value on C compared to the people in sheet 'Data' with A89 but a B lower than the of Name 1 in sheet 'Calc'. 
Return 'Maybe: Person A, Person B'.

I've tried to make a start by just getting the highest values in sheet 'Calc' by combining =ARRAYFORMULA with MAX, but I get either a 'different number' array error or everything is just compared to B3.

Error:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($A3:$A);;$B3&":"&MAX((Data!$B3:$B=$B3)*Data!$C3:$C)&":"&MAX((Data!$B3:$B=$B3)*Data!$D3:$D)))
```

Only calculated with B3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($A3:$A);;$B3&":"&MAX((Data!$B3:$B=$B3)*Data!$C3:$C)&":"&MAX((Data!$B3:$B=$B3)*Data!$D3:$D)))
```

Edit: I've removed the open-ended ranges which at least removed the error I got, but it still doesn't return the desired numbers (it returns either zero or the highest numbers belonging to the first entry, B3). I've updated the sheet accordingly.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($A3:$A999);;$B$3:$B$999&":"&MAX((Data!$B3:$B999=$B$3:$B$999)*Data!$C3:$C999)&":"&MAX((Data!$B3:$B999=$B$3:$B$999)*Data!$D3:$D999)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not found a way to autopopulate it yet, but this solution works for me because I can just copy it to a lot of cells by combining an IF-statement with a ISBLANK() formula.

Basically I've used this, wrapped in a couple of if-statements, changed the returned data according to my needs, and built the code up from there. It returns the desired cell-value from the person with the highest B-value and who's A-value corresponds with the one on the CALC sheet.

```
INDEX(          
    Data!$C:$C
    ;
    MATCH(
        MAXIFS(
            Data!$C$3:$C$100
            ;
            Data!$B$3:$B$100
            ;
            $B3
        )
        ;
        Data!$C:$C
        ;
        0
    )
)
```

The code in column M in the sample-sheet is the code that I've started using. It's not pretty (at all) and could probably be a lot more efficient, but it works and this already took a lot of googling, tries and patience, so I'm a bit at the limit of my google-formula knowledge, haha.

This is the formula I've implemented in this sheet for conditional formatting, should someone need something like it. It picks the maximum value of a column based on a criteria in another:

```
=$E3=MAXIFS($E$3:$E$100;$M$3:$M$100;"Yes")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your two tabs are of different size AND you have open ranges.
Your `Calc` tab is 1002 rows, while `Data` is 2001 rows.

You have 2 alternatives

**Solution 1**
**Add** just one more row in your `Data` tab or delete one from your `Calc` tab.

**Solution 2**
Use closed ranges as in

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($A3:$A888);;$B3:$B888&":"&MAX((Data!$B3:$B888=$B3:$B888)*Data!$C3:$C888)&":"&MAX((Data!$B3:$B888=$B3:$B888)*Data!$D3:$D888)))
```

In either case, **make sure your ranges have the same amount of rows**.

Comment: Will the number of rows be different again when I delete one row later on (e.g. deleting one person's data in 'Data')? Because that's a possibility within the Data range. If so, is there some way to prevent the formula going haywire when that happens?

Comment: You can either add one or delete one. Just make sure your open ranges have the same amount of rows.

Comment: It's updated! Btw, I'm just afraid that -when the sheet's is in use later on- a row gets deleted in 'Data' somehow and the formula breaks because of the different number of rows. So I'm wondering if that's preventable by editing the formula in some way.

Comment: Don't use open ranges. Just say `Data!$B3:$B888=$B3` and change the rest accordingly

Comment: While the Arrayformula works now, the code is not fixed yet, it only grabs the value from the first row. How could I fix that?